# Saving and initializating session values in the model

Tags: php, session, dependency-injection, doctrine

Imagine that I want to login a user. The user sends the validation data, and my controller gets the POST request so it calls a User Repository method in order to registered him.

I'd like to start the user Session with the user data. But how should I start the session? Should it start in the controller or the model? I think it should be the model, since it's my business logic who says that session have to be started. But how? Should I pass the session object to my Repository?

Im using Doctrine for the model layer, and my own framework for the rest. I use dependency injection but I don't see how to get access to the Session from the entities / repositories layer.

The only solution I've got right now is to call the repository method passing the session as a parameter, but it doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think session handling should be done in the controller, but just personal opinion. If you are trying to have a clean separation of concern, it should defiantly be done it the controller. It doesn't make a lot of sense to make Doctrine (which has a very strong focus on abstraction and independence) dependable on the session.

Make a controller which calls a method from model to register the user. The model method returns the user specific data, which you pass to the Session (from controller). You will probably use session in a lot of places, not relevant to model. Why make it stretch to two levels, if you can encapsulate it in one?

Comment: Session would be encapsulated in its own class. There is no need to encapsulate it through the controller layer. 
IMO, if I want to write a session value due to certain business logic, then the model should write it calling this session class.

Controllers should just take care of sending data to the view layer

Comment: Hmmm ok. Probably personal choice, but I still wouldn't put it in the model. Lets say you want to write a desktop app using the same model. It doesn't need session. Why would the model depend on it?

Comment: In that case I'd inject a Dummy Session object (that shares interface with the normal Session handler) to the model, since it's not needed for that particular device. What do you think ?

Comment: If your business logic really depends a lot on session then go with your interface approach. If it is just for the purpose you mentioned I would still keep out of the model. This is just my opinion, not saying I'm right.